# FormatProvider String(s) on the Type String

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I other type like dates can have format strings to change the string appearance of it value.

Just curious, is there any for the type string?
For example.
    `"stack overflow".ToString("T")`  Converts the string to Title Case
    `.ToString("U")` -> Upper case
    `.ToString("L")` -> Lower case

Comment: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: also, why not ToUpper() and ToLower() ?

Comment: @MitchWheat That refers to other types not string like I stated. Provide a specific example of "whatever".ToString("{formatsring}") not String.Format.

Comment: ToUpper() and ToLower() are methods of the string class. Period. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed.aspx

Comment: Yes I know that. Reread the question. **Format Provider Strings** I want do string have any? It doesn't have to uppercase, etc.

Comment: You know that? How come you deleted your comment where you said they weren't. How about you reread that 1st comment?  I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToString()` method converts data from one type to the `string` type. In some cases, for instance with floating point numbers, there are more ways to perform this conversion (for instance, the number of decimals you want to keep). You have to then indicate "how" you want this conversion to be done. If you don't specify how, a default will be used.

You don't have to perform any conversion if you want to "convert" a string to a string, that's why it would not make sense to put the logic you desire in a `ToString()` method.

As Mitch mentioned, `string` does have methods to alter "itself" (you actually get a new string) like `ToLower()` and `Trim()` for instance. If the desired methods do not exist, you can always write string extensions yourself:

```
public static string ToTitle(this string original)
{
    // ... whatever you want here
}
```